# Getting unknown command error when trying to run script via cron

Tags: macos, bash, cron

I recently had to re-install 10.9.5 (default install) and am now finding that bash scripts that run perfectly from the command line (~/Me...) no longer work using crontab. I use crontab to invoke "Diskutil unmount volumeX" but am getting mail from cron saying "diskutil" command not found. Is it a PATH issue and if so how would I fix it.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

`cron` uses `/usr/bin:/bin` as the default `PATH` and `diskutil` is in `/usr/sbin`.

Specify the full path to `diskutil` or add a line like `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` to the start of your crontab.

Enter `which diskutil` to find its path, or enter `echo $PATH` to find the path where your commands are working.

Answer (score 0):

#### Question:

> Is it a PATH issue and if so how would I fix it.

#### Answer to "Is this a PATH issue?":

It most probably is a "PATH issue". But the real issue is ***not knowing*** the true value of `$PATH` that `cron` uses. That is the issue this answer will address.

As a user of `cron`, one of the things you should understand is that although `cron` executes your `crontab` instructions on your behalf, and under your userid, it does this within a different *environment* than you do as a "logged in" user.

Perhaps the easiest way to discover what your environment is when running a job from `cron` is to ask `cron` to tell you! That's easily done as follows:

```
% crontab -e

# in your editor, add the following line, then save & close your new crontab 

* * * * * printenv > /Users/$USER/mycronenvironment.txt 2>&1

# now wait for the output:

% tail -f ~/mycronenvironment.txt
```

You'll want to stop this shortly, so edit and save your `crontab`. Your output will resemble this:

> SHELL=/bin/sh
> USER=seamus
> PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
> PWD=/Users/seamus
> SHLVL=1
> HOME=/Users/seamus
> LOGNAME=seamus
> _=/usr/bin/printenv

Note the `PATH` variable is limited to `/usr/bin` & `bin`. So - your `cron` job will look **nowhere else** for a file. You may now wish to compare this *environment* against the one in your *interactive login* shell. Simply run `printenv` from your login shell (`zsh` on later model Macs):

```
% printenv
...
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Apple/usr/bin  
...
```

This difference in the `PATH` environment variables explains the source of an "unknown command" error generated by `cron`: the command is not on the `PATH` of the shell used by `cron`.

#### Answer to "How do I fix this?":

In general, there are two methods:

1. Use a full path specification for everything in your `crontab`

   For example : `/usr/sbin/diskutil unmount volumeX`
2. Define (re-define) `PATH` in your `crontab`

   And as usual there are numerous ways to do this. If you want to use your "logged-in user" `PATH` as the `PATH` for your "cron user":

   ```
   % echo $PATH
   /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

   % crontab -e
   # copy and paste the $PATH string at the top of the file as follows:

   PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

   # save & close your `crontab`  
   # you can re-activate the `printenv` cron job again to verify the new path
   ```

   A *variation* on this approach could be as follows:

   - Create a file named (for example) `~/.cronpath`
   - Put a single line in this file: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:<other folders>` where <other folders> is a colon-separated list of dirs you wish to add to the default `PATH`.
   - Source the file `~/.cronpath` at reboot in your `crontab`:

   ```sh
   @reboot . /Users/$USER/.cronpath

   ...
   # remainder of crontab entries
   ```