# cron queueing bash and python scripts

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, python, cron

I'm currently looking to understand and get comfortable with crontab queues on my macbook pro. I recently solved an issue where my simple bash script would not execute. It turns out I had to move my bash script and its output in the `/Users/myusername/` path. Before I had it in the `/Users/myusername/Desktop/`. This post can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110897/simple-bash-script-doesnt-cron-properly?noredirect=1#comment113370465_64110897

My question: Do all of my bash and python scripts need to be housed in `/Users/myusername` path always? Is there no workaround?

Answer (score 3):

#### Question:

> My question: Do all of my bash and python scripts need to be housed in `/Users/myusername` path always? Is there no workaround?

#### Answer:

No. You can locate your bash and python scripts anywhere you like. However, there are *additional requirements*:

1. Your `cron` jobs run with a different *ENVIRONMENT* than when you run them; e.g. `$PATH`. Consequently, you should use a **full path specification** for specifying your scripts in the `crontab`; **for example** use:

```
* * * * * /opt/local/bin/python3 /some/dir/you/choose/myscript.py
```

2. On my Mac (Catalina) I've found it necessary to give "Full Disk Access" privileges to `cron`. YMMV on a different OS version. Here's how:

`System Preferences` **->** `Security & Privacy` **->** `Privacy` tab:

[image]

3. At least while *debugging* your `cron` job, you should consider redirecting any error messages (`stderr`) to a file - otherwise they wind up in `/dev/null` which is not helpful! Continuing with the above example:

```
* * * * * /opt/local/bin/python3 /some/dir/you/choose/myscript.py >> /Home/<username>/MyCronLog.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to be sure you grant permissions to the elements and use full paths for everything. Just because a script runs when you are in an interactive shell, doesn’t mean they are correct in a limited shell.

[Here are super debugging tips](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402179/5472) on a recent question.

- [cron and "command not found"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298775/)
- [cronjobs do not run](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402132/)
- [Getting unknown command error when trying to run script via cron](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152809/)